# Jupyter Notebook confuses math bracket symbols with html tags

Tags: jupyter-notebook

In Jupyter notebook, a markdown cell with:

```
$$\langle p'^2\rangle$$
$$<p'^2>$$
```

will display:

[image]

Both options look acceptable.

But when the notebook is downloaded as an html page, the second line is not understood as math and is then displayed as text:

$$$$$

Answer (score 0):

The thing is the `<p` symbol get confused with html tag. 
Simple trick, but good to know !